# Need image to change when checkbox is selected

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form that requires the user to make a selection from a drown down box, when they make the selection the logo on the top of the page will change to match their selection. 
here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k8ss/).
So my problem is this, I want to be able to post the name of the selection in the drop down box to mysql but being as how the value is already being used by the javascript to change the image all that posts in the db is the name of the image and not the value in the box.

What I would like to do is instead of using the drop down box to change the image, how can I use check boxes to accomplish the same thing? I have a default logo that is always displayed on the form until a selection is made so I need to keep that in place as well.

here is the code in the jsfiddle

```
<br/><br/>

<select id="dd" onChange="swapImage()" style="width: 150px">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="http://xxxs.com/demo1/decals/falcons2013.jpg">Falcons</option>
<option value="http://xxxxx.com/demo1/decals/gvklogo2013.png">Green Valley   Knights</option>
<option value="http://xxxxx.com/demo1/decals/longhorns2013.jpg">Longhorns</option>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript

```
function swapImage(){
var image = document.getElementById("logoimage");
var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
image.src = dropd.value;    
};
```

Comment: Try radio buttons instead of checkboxes, checkboxes allow multiple selections, whereas radio buttons only allow a single selection (which is what you should use here)

Comment: thanks pattyd, I have a script that only allows one checkbox to be checked at a time, if a users selects another checkbox it will uncheck the checked box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using checkboxes will be a little more challenging, unless you make them work like a radio group. If you want to keep the select, you can put the img src at the `title`, allowing you to use the value -

```
<select id="dd" onChange="swapImage()" style="width: 150px">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Falcons" title="http://xxxxx.com/demo1/decals/falcons2013.jpg" >Falcons</option>
    <option value="Green Valley Knights" title="http://xxxxx.com/demo1/decals/gvklogo2013.png">Green Valley Knights</option>
    <option value="Longhorns" title="http://xxxxx.com/demo1/decals/longhorns2013.jpg">Longhorns</option>
</select>
```

Then in your js, get the selected option title -

```
function swapImage(){
var image = document.getElementById("logoimage");
var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].title;   
};
```

see this updated jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/UtcTc/

**edit**
if you want to save the selected img src, I would recommend creating a hidden element just below select

```
<input type="hidden" name="img_url" id="img_url" />
```

then change your `swapImage()` to

```
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("logoimage");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
    image.src = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].title;
    document.getElementById("img_url").value = dropd.options[dropd.selectedIndex].title;    
};
```

which can then be captured on form post -

```
$img_url = $_POST['img_url']
```

Comment: Thanks Sean that's EXACTLY what I was wanting to do but couldn't figure out!

Comment: would you happen to know how I can now store the path to the selected logo in MySQL? can this javascript be modified to say if this team is selected then store path to this logo? or something like that?

Comment: see my edit above. I would use a hidden input, and set the value in your `swapImage()` function.

Comment: Sean I tried something similar to this just different names and it didn't work, do I put the hidden field below the <select> or </select>? when I added it below the <select> all of the option values were outside of the drop down box when I viewed the form

Comment: ok I added it just before the </select> and the values are back in the drop down but it still doesn't store the path to the selected image in the database.

Comment: it has to be outside the select. it can be before `<input ... /><select>...</select>` or after `<select>...</select><input ... />`, just needs to be somewhere inside the form tags `<form><input ... /></form>`

Comment: since you have `<input type="hidden" name="logo_src" id="logosrc" />` you need to do `$logo_source = $_POST['logo_src']`. Input name must be the same as `$_POST` key. Also, you still have it before the closing `</select>`. Move it after `</select><input type="hidden" name="logo_src" id="logosrc" />`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33003/discussion-between-user2447848-and-sean)